# RarCrack ampersand in character list

Tags: xml, ampersand

I'm trying to recover a zip file that I've forgotten the password for. I know roughly what it is and so I have a set of characters that I want to input into RarCrack's list. The problem I have is that one of the characters is an ampersand '&'.
RarCrack uses an xml file that you can edit which has the following line in it:

```
<abc>abcdefg</abc>
```

this controls the characters to use however if I add the ampersand to the list then I hit problems.  I've also tried using the following:

```
&amp;
&amp;amp;
&#038;
```

has anyone ever managed to get this to work or is it a limitation of RarCrack?

Thanks